Prove that $5\log +\sqrt n$ is $O(\sqrt n)$
I am trying to prove that $5\log +\sqrt n$ is $O(\sqrt n)$.
So I need to do: $5\log +\sqrt n\le C\sqrt n$ and I need to find $C$ and $n_0$ that satisfies the equation.
Looking at it I know is $O(\sqrt n)$, but I cannot really find $C$ and $n_0$ that satisfies the equation because I cannot find a way to isolate the $5\log $
What I did is: $5\log n/\sqrt n\le C$.
But now I cannot find a $C$ bigger than something that has a $N$ (on this case $5\log n$) in the other side that can grows indefinitely. I can always assume $5\log n/\sqrt n$ will be a really tiny number if $n$ goes to infinity, so $C$ is $5$, but not sure this is the way here. I suppose I messed up somewhere but cannot see.

Did you mean $\log n$? Or what $\log_n$ means?

What did you mean? Something like $log \sqrt n $

yes, log(n), I guess the math plotting I did is not correct, let me try to change

Please next time format your formulas. (Here, I did it for you.)

You are on the right track. Argue that $$\exists A\quad\forall n\ge1\quad\log n/\sqrt n\le A$$ because this sequence converges (to $0$), and you are done: $5\log +\sqrt n\le C\sqrt n$, for $C:=5A+1$.

It does not answer exactly but I think it helps. I will accept it :)
